# multiple post into single page

Tags: pages

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__in' => array( 2770, 10, 266, 1558 ) //list of page_ids
        );
        $page_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $page_query->have_posts() ) :
            echo '<div class="pages-on-page">';
            //print any general title or any header here//
            while( $page_query->have_posts() ) : $page_query->the_post();
                echo '<div class="page-on-page" id="page_id-' . $post->9011 . '">';
        //print any output you want per page//
        echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
            echo '</div>';
        else:

        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: Please add some descriptions, write a little bit details on your problem, mention clearly what problem you're facing and what kinda goal you wanna achieve. It'll help us to solve your problem better.

Comment: i want to migret old site but some wordpress functions are change so i want show the multiple post on single page so how i can??

Comment: Edit your question and add this comment details to your question.

Comment: i want to migret old wordpress site and merge some multiple posts on single page so how i can??

Comment: yes i do this but not any change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I understood you need to show those pages content through that query. So you can modify your code like below-

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__in' => array( 2770, 10, 266, 1558 ) //list of page_ids
        );
        $page_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $page_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
            <div class="pages-on-page">
            <?php
            //print any general title or any header here//
            while( $page_query->have_posts() ) : $page_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div>
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
            endwhile;
            echo '</div>';
        else:

        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how to display all post on single page ? this porgram is run but this all pages are effected.

Comment: Well there are multiple ways to do it. My favorite is shortcode. You'll define a shortcode and place that shortcode where you wanna show all the posts  then it will show all the posts. Give me some time I'll update my answer.

Comment: okk so how to create shortcode?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API check this out.